# parsing Float with 'get' from ByteString not behaving as expected

Tags: parsing, haskell

In the context of creating a simple STL parser, I found some, at least to me, unexpected behavior in `get` from `Data.Binary`. It appears to me that it does not stop reading the `ByteString` after the 32 bits that I would assume it should.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
module STLTransform where

import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL
import Data.Binary
import Data.Binary.Get
import Data.Binary.Put
import Data.Word
import Numeric.LinearAlgebra
import GHC.Float
import System.Endian

getTriangle = do
  normal   <- getR3
  vertices <- sequence $ take 3 $ trace (show normal) $ repeat getR3
  return (normal, vertices)
  where getR3 = fmap (vector.fmap float2Double)
              $ sequence $ take 3 $ repeat get

getSTL :: Get ([Word8], Word32, [(Vector R, [Vector R])], Word16)
getSTL = do
  header <- sequence $ take 80 $ repeat get
  number <- fmap (toBE32) $ get
  triangles <- sequence $ take (fromIntegral number) $ repeat getTriangle
  attribute <- get
  return (header, number, triangles, attribute)

readSTL fn = BL.readFile fn >>= return.runGet getSTL
```

Attempting to read an STL-file using this code, I would get an error like

```
*Main STLTransform> readSTL "test.stl"
*** Exception: Data.Binary.Get.runGet at position 1268784: not enough bytes
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
error, called at libraries/binary/src/Data/Binary/Get.hs:351:5 in binary-0.8.6.0:Data.Binary.Get
```

After some debugging, I isolated the problem to `getTriangle`, and more specifically the parsing of `Float` values. By replacing `float2Double` with `(\a -> fromIntegral (a :: Word32))`

```
getTriangle = do
  normal   <- getR3
  vertices <- sequence $ take 3 $ trace (show normal) $ repeat getR3
  return (normal, vertices)
  where getR3 = fmap (vector.fmap (\a -> fromIntegral (a :: Word32)))
              $ sequence $ take 3 $ repeat get
```

I get code that runs as I intended (although obviously with incorrect numbers). So the the question is, why are `Float` and `Word32` treated differently? Is not `Float` also a 32 bit value?

The version of the package used is `binary-0.8.6.0`

EDIT:
The corrected version of the function is

```
getTriangle :: Get (Vector R, [Vector R], Word16)
getTriangle = do
  normal    <- getR3
  vertices  <- sequence $ take 3 $ repeat getR3
  attribute <- get
  return (normal, vertices, attribute)
  where getR3 = fmap (vector.fmap float2Double)
              $ sequence $ take 3 $ repeat getFloatle
```

Unrelated to the stated issue, but corrected from the original post, the attribute is on the triangle level, not on the file level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `Binary` instance of `Float`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-0.8.7.0/docs/src/Data.Binary.Class.html#line-685) parses a pair 
`(Integer, Int)` and [then uses `encodeFloat :: Integer -> Int -> Float`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:encodeFloat), which is why it takes more than 32 bits.

This is a known issue left around for backwards compatibility: https://github.com/kolmodin/binary/issues/69

Don't use `get` blindly, there is more than one way to encode things. In this case, there are other parsers for 32 bit formats of `Float`: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-0.8.7.0/docs/Data-Binary-Get.html#v:getFloatbe